# Volitional sentence vs. imperative sentence

Tags: sentence-patterns

What's the difference? Is a volitional sentence simply a weaker form of an imperative sentence?

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't aware that we had them in English.  My wife uses them quite a lot, but that's because she speaks Mandarin.

Given that this is something from Chinese or Japanese, which is being applied to English (either by you or something you have read/heard), please give a precise definition of what you mean.

[Edit:  Why on Earth was that down-voted?  Does someone believe that English has volitional sentences?  It is for the OP to clarify the meaning of the (Asian-language) term, so that people can respond to it in relation to things with similar aspects in English.]

Comment: Perhaps we don't have a volitional verb conjugation, but I'd say we still have *volitional sentences*. That is, we can clearly express the same intent/desire in our sentences despite lacking a specific very form. (BTW, I didn't down-vote)

Comment: Sure, but, because there is no accepted syntactic/semantic definition for English of "volitional sentences", the OP has to tell us what *he* means by it (it's different in Chinese and Japanese, and is just a simple adjective-noun combination in English, which could mean many things).  How can we tell the difference between two things when we don't know for sure what one of them is?

Comment: I agree. There is no accepted definition of "volitional sentence" in English.

Comment: Perhaps the downvote was because maybe they thought this doesn't answer the question as such, but asks for more info, which could be a comment.